# Does C#/VB.NET using statement actually do anything with classes that do not implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If i have something like the following:

```
public class Myclass{

//some resources

}
```

and then in another class i do the following:

```
using(Myclass myclass = new Myclass()) {
// do things with myclass instance

}
```

Does the using statement in this case actually provide any use? `Myclass` has not implemented the `IDisposable` interface so there isn't any `Dispose()` method to call. Am i thinking about this correctly?

Comment: It won't compile if `Myclass` doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: "Does the using statement in this case actually provide any use?" No, because [it does not compile](http://ideone.com/Ov4Iw1).

Comment: Why would you use `using` if your class doesn't implement IDisposable?  That makes little sense.

Answer (score 5):

If your class is not implementing `IDisposable` then you can't use it inside `using` statement. It would be a compile time error.

Other than that, `using` statement translates into `try-finally` block and at the end of using statement, `Dispose` is called *(even in case of an exception)*. There is nothing magical done by CLR to *actually* dispose the object, it all depends on the implementation of `Dispose`. You can have an empty implementation of `Dispose` method  and there will be no effect.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `using` with types that don't implement `IDisposable`. You will get a compiler error. That's it.

- [MSDN C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx): ... All such types must implement the `IDisposable` interface....
- [MSDN VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) ...Required. The class of the resource. The class must implement the `IDisposable` interface...

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e9htskb1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the CS1674 compiler error you get.